# Crystal Reporting in MVVM pattern and prism lib

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, crystal-reports, prism

I've just read this [link](http://scn.sap.com/thread/2025845) and follow the steps.but my crystal report viewer is not posting the report, but doesn't throw any Exception.

How do I fix this?

I've tried it in coding behind the view and it ran smoothly.

**VIEWMODEL**

```
    using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;
using FINNANCE_PROGRAM.Views.ReportViewer;
using Prism.Commands;
using Prism.Mvvm;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;

namespace FINNANCE_PROGRAM.ViewModels.ReportViewer
{
    public class MonthlyTrialBalanceReportViewerViewModel : BindableBase
    {

        public DelegateCommand LoadMonthlyReport { get; set; }


        private ReportDocument _MyReportSource;
        public ReportDocument MyReportSource
        {
            get { return _MyReportSource; }
            set
            {
                if (_MyReportSource != null)
                {
                    SetProperty(ref _MyReportSource, value);
                }
            }
        }






        public MonthlyTrialBalanceReportViewerViewModel()
        {
            LoadMonthlyReport = new DelegateCommand(OpenLoadMonthlyReport);
            MyReportSource = new ReportDocument();
        }



        private void OpenLoadMonthlyReport()
        {
            ReportDocument rpts = new ReportDocument();
           // MonthlyTrialBalanceReportViewer repviewer = new MonthlyTrialBalanceReportViewer();
            rpts.Load(@"E:\TEST_USER\Desktop\FINAL_DECISION_FIN_PROG\2016\FINNANCE_PROGRAM 1-26-2016\FINNANCE_PROGRAM\bin\Debug\ReportDesign\MonthlyTrialBalanceReportDoc.rpt");
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr;



            dt.Columns.Add("Dept");
            dt.Columns.Add("Item_No");
            dt.Columns.Add("AccountCode");
            dt.Columns.Add("AccountName");
            dt.Columns.Add("Branch");
            dt.Columns.Add("OpeningBalance");
            dt.Columns.Add("TotalDebit");
            dt.Columns.Add("TotalCredit");
            dt.Columns.Add("EndingBalance");

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr[0] = "11111";
            dr[1] = "22222";
            dr[2] = "22222";
            dr[3] = "33333";
            dr[4] = "44444";
            dr[5] = "55555";
            dr[6] = "66666";
            dr[7] = "77777";
            dr[8] = "88888";

            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            rpts.SetDataSource(dt);
            //repviewer.RepViewer.ViewerCore.ReportSource = rpts;
           MyReportSource = rpts;
        }
    }
}
```

**VIEW (XAML)**

```
<UserControl    x:Class="FINNANCE_PROGRAM.Views.ReportViewer.MonthlyTrialBalanceReportViewer"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:prism="http://prismlibrary.com/"
             xmlns:Viewer="clr-namespace:SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer;assembly=SAPBusinessObjects.WPF.Viewer" 
             xmlns:ReportB="clr-namespace:FINNANCE_PROGRAM.AllReports"
                prism:ViewModelLocator.AutoWireViewModel="True"

             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="500" d:DesignWidth="800">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="200"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>


        <StackPanel Grid.Row="1">
            <Button  Command="{Binding LoadMonthlyReport}" Content="Load" />
        </StackPanel>





        <Viewer:CrystalReportsViewer Name="RepViewer" ReportB:ReportSourceBehaviour.ReportSource="{Binding Path=MyReportSource, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=FrameworkElement}}"  Grid.Column="1"  Grid.Row="1" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: I have this problem already but with another reporting component, I think it is problem of thread safe, take a look at the thread safety, good day

Comment: hi sir toumir, is it solve your problem ? thanks for your reply

Comment: yes, we have solved the problem,  I can't remember exactly how the problem was solved, but it resolved. my comment provides you maybe an idea that can help you.

Comment: ok thank you sir @toumir. if you remember the solution can you please give me an idea regarding it.. but as of now, i've just looking for another solution just to reach the goal that to bind the Report source of Crystal report..

Comment: yes of course, good luck

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your binding is wrong.  Try this:

ReportB:ReportSourceBehaviour.ReportSource="{Binding MyReportSource}"

Comment: hi sir @Brian Lagunas, i've already tried it. but still the same problem..:(

Answer (score 0):

You should use `PropertyChangedEventHandler` on your `MyReportSource` property